# Error: PostCSS plugin autoprefixer requires PostCSS 8. Update PostCSS or downgrade this plugin

Tags: reactjs, npm, postcss

I am getting this error whenever I run npm start.
I tried a couple of fixes but none of them work for me. I tried to change the version of autoprefixer to 9.8.6 but it didn't work.
Please help me with this issue

This is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "reactgallery",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.5.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "npm run watch:css && react-scripts start",
    "build": "npm run build:css && react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "build:css": "postcss src/assets/tailwind.css -o src/assets/main.css",
    "watch:css": "postcss src/assets/tailwind.css -o src/assets/main.css"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^9.8.6",
    "postcss-cli": "^7.1.2",
    "tailwindcss": "^1.8.10"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 118, accepted):

### Quick fix

Downgrade your autoprefixer to version 9, use

> "autoprefixer": "^9.0.0"

in your dev dependencies.

### More details

PostCSS was updated to version 8, however, PostCSS CLI has not yet been updated to handle PostCSS plugins which use the new PostCSS 8+ API. Autoprefixer uses the new PostCSS 8 API since version 10.

This is documented under **known issues** in the [PostCSS](https://github.com/postcss/postcss/releases/tag/8.0.0) GitHub page.

Once PostCSS CLI is updated to handle plugins that use the new PostCSS 8+ API, this will likely not be an issue. But until then, you may need to downgrade some PostCSS plugins to avoid errors.

Comment: Thanks for your response.This didn't work for me. I'm still getting this error. Error: PostCSS plugin autoprefixer requires PostCSS 8. Update PostCSS or downgrade this plugin.

Comment: @RishiPurwar did you delete your node_modules folder and run `npm install` or `yarn install` ?

Comment: Update: postcss-cli v8 supports postcss v8

Comment: Yes, postcss-cli v8 currently supports postcss v8

Comment: "@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat": "^2.2.4",
"autoprefixer": "^9.8.6",
"postcss": "^7.0.35",

use these combination. it should work..

Comment: `npm install --save-dev autoprefixer@^9.0.0` helped me

Answer (score 41):

I am not sure about this but can you try installing postcss as a dependency?

```
npm i postcss
```

Answer (score 40):

If you're having this problem and you're using Tailwind CSS v2, try this

```
npm uninstall tailwindcss postcss autoprefixer
npm install tailwindcss@npm:@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat postcss@^7 autoprefixer@^9
```

source: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation#post-css-7-compatibility-build

Comment: when you run the command in MacOS, you might  encounter the issue `zsh: no matches found: postcss@^7`.  try to run this `npm install tailwindcss@npm:@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat 'postcss@^7' 'autoprefixer@^9'`

reference: https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/discussions/3575

Answer (score 10):

Ok, to me was fixed removing **package-lock.json** and installing:

```
"tailwindcss": "^1.8.10"
"postcss-cli": "^7.1.0"
"autoprefixer": "^9.7.5"
```

Comment: Removing the package-lock did it for me.  But I'm using ^9.8.5.

Answer (score 8):

```
"dependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^9.8.6",
    "postcss": "^8.0.0",
    "postcss-cli": "^8.1.0",
    "tailwindcss": "npm:@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat@^2.0.2",
},
```

Dependecies object and version can be modified directly in the `package.json` file and it work

Comment: in April 2021, this was the only combination working for me without error in a react-tailwind setup, probably due to the tailwind-compat-build.

Answer (score 7):

These steps worked for me. This was from [github](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/issues/2831#issuecomment-731038281)

```
npm uninstall tailwindcss postcss autoprefixer
npm install tailwindcss@latest postcss@latest autoprefixer@latest

npx tailwindcss init -p

npm uninstall tailwindcss postcss autoprefixer
npm install tailwindcss@npm:@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat postcss@^7 autoprefixer@^9
```

Answer (score 5):

Based on documentation [link](https://github.com/postcss/postcss/wiki/PostCSS-8-for-end-users) are drop some support for old NodeJS and you must upgrade manually the packages. Example in my case for a project based on webpack need just to update those dependencies:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^10.0.2",
    "postcss": "^8.1.7",
    "postcss-loader": "^4.0.4"
  }
```

So you do not need to downgrade **autoprefixer** :)

Comment: Works for me - was not able to add "post-css" package via terminal but after adding the line manually into package.json and reinstalling everything was fine.

Comment: YAY! Thank you! This actually worked. This has been haunting me for what feels like years. This works with gulp-postcss plugin which is great :) To think the answer was as simple as "just manually install the packages"

Answer (score 4):

the following combo works as of Oct 2020

```
  ...
  "dependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^9.8.6",
    "postcss-cli": "^8.1.0",
    "tailwindcss": "^1.9.2"
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

For Next.js 10 you just have to do

```
npm install tailwindcss@latest postcss@latest autoprefixer@latest
```

Source [This issue here](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/issues/2799#issuecomment-730548333)

Answer (score 2):

Using the official solution fix for [PostCSS 7 compatibility build](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation#post-css-7-compatibility-build)

```
yarn remove tailwindcss postcss autoprefixer
yarn add -D tailwindcss@npm:@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat @tailwindcss/postcss7-compat postcss@^7 autoprefixer@^9
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem with Laravel-mix 5 and PostCSS 8 and Tailwind 2.
With Laravel-mix 6 (beta at the moment) this was solved.

```
npm install laravel-mix@next --save-dev
```

Answer (score -1):

Its Simple,

```
npm install postcss@^8
```

It worked very well for me.