# This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above. Exit status 1

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

I want to integrate tailwind.css  in my react.js app but after doing some steps while I go to run my app it shows error like I have attach picture in the following.

```
     ["scripts": {
        "start": "npm run watch:css && react-scripts start",
        "build": "npm run build:css && react-scripts build",
        "test": "react-scripts test",
        "eject": "react-scripts eject",
        "build:css": "postcss src/components/books/CSS/talwind.css -o src/components/books/CSS/main.css",
        "watch:css": "postcss src/components/books/CSS/talwind.css -o src/components/books/CSS/main.css"
      },
      "eslintConfig": {
        "extends": "react-app"
      },
      "browserslist": {
        "production": \[
          ">0.2%",
          "not dead",
          "not op_mini all"
        \],
        "development": \[
          "last 1 chrome version",
          "last 1 firefox version",
          "last 1 safari version"
        \]
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "autoprefixer": "^10.0.1",
        "postcss-cli": "^8.2.0",
        "tailwindcss": "^1.9.6"
      }
    }][1]
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Du0H.png)

Here is my terminal snippet that show what error exactly I'm facing.

Answer (score 0):

Try to downgrade autoprefixer dependency like suggested here: [https://github.com/parcel-bundler/parcel/issues/5160"](https://github.com/parcel-bundler/parcel/issues/5160%22)

Comment: Contents not found please provide useful link

Answer (score 0):

This is the generic error message you will receive from npm when packages throw an error:

> This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above. Exit status 1

Like it says, it is not a problem with npm and you need to look at the preceeding lines to figure out what your actual problem is. The image you posted tells you exactly what the error is and what you should do about it:

> Error: PostCSS plugin autoprefixer requires PostCSS 8

> Migration guide for end users: https://github.com/postcss/postcss/wiki/PostCSS-8-for-end-users

From that page, and from your config, it looks like you're using create-react-app. Since that's the case, you will probably need to downgrade your dependencies. Per [a note on that page](https://github.com/postcss/postcss/wiki/PostCSS-8-for-end-users#create-react-app):

> Create React App
> ❌ Support this PR to get PostCSS 8 in CRA 4.0. For now, you need to avoid using PostCSS 8 plugins.

[Per this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64057023/error-postcss-plugin-autoprefixer-requires-postcss-8-update-postcss-or-downgra), you may have to downgrade:

- `autoprefixer` to `"^9.0.0"`
- `postcss-cli` to `"^7.0.0"`

Comment: I have downgraded the dependencies versions but not fixed

Comment: @MDABDULKADIR to confirm, you now have `"autoprefixer": "^9.0.0"` & `"postcss-cli": "^7.0.0"`? Is the error exactly the same? `Error: PostCSS plugin autoprefixer requires PostCSS 8`? Can you try removing `node_modules` and re-run `npm install`?

Answer (score 0):

Do the following steps

first uninstall tailwindcss postcss autoprefixer

`npm uninstall tailwindcss postcss autoprefixer`

then reinstall with postcss 7, autoprefixer 9

`npm install tailwindcss@npm:@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat postcss@^7 autoprefixer@^9`

Hope it will resolve your issue.